# Detect duplicate foldernames (before the folderextension)

Tags: powershell, duplicates, directory

I have a folderstructure on which I want to detect duplicate foldernames e.g.

```
C:\APP10001.001
C:\APP10001.002
C:\APP10002.001
C:\APP10003.002
C:\APP10003.003
C:\APP10003.004
C:\APP10004.002
```

In this case I want to detect that there are folders with the same name (wihtout the folder extension), C:\APP10001 and C:\APP10003.

Output should look like:

```
APP10001     2
APP10003     3
```

Comment: Read all files (Get-ChildItem -Directory) use split(method) for the foldername and check for duplicates (google).

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat Each individual element of the `(Get-ChildItem -Directory)` collection is an instance of the `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` type. Utilize its properties `Extension` and `Name` rather than string splitting.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service - you've not shown any of your own code or any indication you've tried researching/searching for a solution. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!) I'd recommend reading [ask] and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. Your question is likely to be down-voted and/or closed until you include these basics.

Comment: Look at `Get-ChildItem -Path '...' -Directory` and `Group-Object`

Comment: `Get-ChildItem C:\APP* -Dir|Group-Object {$_.Name.split('.')[0]} -NoElement`

Comment: Great work and just a oneliner. This was exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.